# How to convert stylemap with adduniquevaluerules to openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openlayers, style

I am new to openlayers. I have following code in openlayers 2.

```
for (var i=0;i<wfslayers.length;i++) {

    var subteStyleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
            'strokeWidth': 1,
            'strokeOpacity': 1,
            'fillOpacity': 0.5,
            'fillColor':"orange",
            'strokeColor':"orange",
            'pointRadius': 3
        }),
        "select": new OpenLayers.Style({
            fillColor:"#00FFFF",
            strokeColor:"#00FFFF",
        })
    });

    var object=wfslayers[i];
    var styles=[];

    for (var j=0;j<wfsStyles.length; j++) {
        if(object.wfs_id==wfsStyles[j].wfs_id) {
            styles=wfsStyles[j].data;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (styles[0]) {
        var category=styles[0].attribute_name;
        var lookup={};
        for (var k=0;k<styles.length;k++) {
            var style=styles[k];
            lookup[style.attribute_value]={
                strokeColor: style.strokecolor, 
                strokeWidth: style.strokewidth,
                fillColor: style.fillcolor,
                pointRadius: style.pointradius
            };
        }
        subteStyleMap.addUniqueValueRules("default", category, lookup); 
    }
    var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(object.name, { 
        layerid: object.label_text,
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:"+object.srid), 
        styleMap: subteStyleMap,
    }
    wfscatalog.push(layer);
}
```

With the help of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093975/openlayers3-make-choropleth-map-with-geojson , I tried to write the equivalent openlayers3 code. But I need help on stylemap. Please help.

```
for (var i=0;i<wfslayers.length;i++) {

    var styleNormal = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(255, 128, 64, 1)',
            width: 1
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 128, 64, 0.5)'
        })
    });

    var styleSelect = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#00FFFF'
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#00FFFF'
        })
    });
    var select = new ol.interaction.Select({style:styleSelect});

    var object=wfslayers[i];
    var styles=[];

    for (var j=0;j<wfsStyles.length; j++) {
        if(object.wfs_id==wfsStyles[j].wfs_id) {
            styles=wfsStyles[j].data;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (styles[0]) {
        var category=styles[0].attribute_name;
        var lookup={};
        for (var k=0;k<styles.length;k++) {
            var style=styles[k];
            lookup[style.attribute_value]={[
                new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: style.strokecolor,
                        width: style.strokewidth
                    }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: style.fillcolor
                    })
                });
            ]};
        }
    }
    var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        projection: "EPSG:"+object.srid
        style: function(feature, resolution) {
            return lookup[feature.get(category)];
        }
    });
    layer.layerid=object.label_text;
    wfscatalog.push(layer);
}
```

Comment: Any answers please??

Comment: @erilem can you please answer?

Comment: @juminet Please help